# SQL Server Cross Apply speed issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two views on separate servers that I am joining together into one view.

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT v1.Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as Name, v1.Year as Year
 FROM AgentCallsByMonth v1
 UNION
 SELECT v2.Name as Name, v2.Year as Year
 FROM BH1PCIMD01.eGActiveDB.dbo.AgentChatsByMonth v2
 ) as u CROSS APPLY (
              SELECT       
                     ISNULL(v1.[Month],v2.[Month]) as [Month],
                     ISNULL(v2.[Chats], 0) AS [Chats], ISNULL(v1.[Calls], 0) AS [Calls]               
              FROM master..spt_values v 
                LEFT JOIN AgentCallsByMonth v1 ON v.number = v1.[MM] AND v1.Name = u.Name and v1.Year=u.Year
                LEFT JOIN BH1PCIMD01.eGActiveDB.dbo.AgentChatCountByMonth v2 ON v.number = v2.[MM] AND v2.Name = u.Name and v2.Year=u.Year
              WHERE v.type = 'P' AND v.number < 12 and u.Year = 2012
              ) o
```

For some reason this is taking forever. If I pull the data from the tables individually it takes less than 30 seconds. Last run of the query above is at 24 minutes and counting.

A little background on what needs to happen.

I have two tables that have a user name, month in a 00-mon format, and a count. Now some months are null as the user did not have any items in count, thus they do not populate. So we are creating the months and putting 0's in there. However in the other table they could have some items in count for a month they did not have a count in the other table.

For example.

**Table 1**

```
JoeUser 01-Jan 48
JoeUser 03-Mar 12
JoeUser 09-Sep 3
```

**Table 2**

```
JoeUser 01-Jan 12
JoeUser 02-Feb 4
JoeUser 05-May 6
```

This is the resulting output:

```
JoeUser 01-Jan 48 12
JoeUser 02-Feb 0 4
JoeUser 03-Mar 12 0
JoeUser 04-Apr 0 0
JoeUser 05-May 0 6
JoeUser 06-June 0 0
etc
```

Comment: The query just finished at 34 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with JOIN?

Comment: Issues like this are debugged by looking at the execution. Please post it.

Comment: Please post the Query Plan.  Preferably the Actual plan rather than the Estimated plan, but either is good as a start.

Comment: Also, it is very helpful to know what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: @JDRoberson . . . It is very hard to know what is going wrong.  Are the tables too big?  Is the connection between the servers too slow?  Is the cross apply resulting in bad optimization?  Are the joins within each subquery the problem?  Take the advice of replacing the apply with a join and work from there.  Or, copy the remote tables to temporary tables and use them instead.

Comment: Plan is at http://goo.gl/1BrgA

Comment: OK, I've looked at the query plan, first, the COLLATE doesn't look to be the problem for now.  Secondly, several of the Tables in this query are actually Views which means that the query is doing some things quite different from what is apparent here.  We will need to see those View definitions to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the comments before mine, but something else I should point out is that adding the collation using "COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" - will most prob cause a slow down, especially if you table is rather large. Remember, it has to do this for every single row returned.

Comment: Actually the overhead of COLLATE itself is unlikely to have much performance impact here.  On the other hand, the fact that the COLLATE is part of the sub queries output column definition, and that same column is used in the implicit CROSS APPLY join conditions *could* be causing a big performance problem by suppressing the use of appropriate indexing and/or hash keys.  But we cannot tell without the query plan ...

Comment: u.Name is used in the sub-query join. Given that we have no further information this answer is the best guess the OP can get. +1

Comment: @JDRoberson: One way would be to redefine the table column so that all text in your database uses the same collation.